# Root finding problem involving newtons method

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

[image]

I attached pictures of the equation I'm supposed to find the root of using newtons method. My code is giving me a big root, it should be close to 7.

```
from math import *
def newton(x):

    fx= (((3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5)))*(1-exp(-.12*x))))-1)
    dfx= (.12*(3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5)))*(1-exp(-.12*x))-.12*x))

    tolerance= .000001
    x0=100
    xnew = x0
    xold= x0-1
    iterations =0
    while (abs(xnew - xold) > tolerance or iterations>1000):

        xold= xnew
        xnew= xnew- (fx/dfx)
        iterations= iterations +1 
        return abs(xnew)
```

Comment: Nice. What's the question?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: call the function by inputting newton(7)

Comment: or what ever value for x

Comment: Your method discards x, sets the initial condition to 100, and never reomputes the function value or derivative in `xnew= xnew- (fx/dfx)`

Comment: how would i fix it

Comment: Don't discard the initial value and recompute the function and derivative at each step.